# Reference for the upper bound of trace of product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, reference-request, trace

For two real-valued square matrices $A$ and $B$, it has been shown that (for example, in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321133/upper-bound-for-the-trace-of-the-product-of-a-matrix-and-a-positive-matrix)),

$$ tr(AB) \leq \lVert A \rVert Tr(\sqrt{B^{\prime}B}).$$

I am looking for a reference about this result to cite in an article.

Comment: FYI, MSE provides pre-made BibTex citations for questions on the site. Just press the "Cite" button under the question, between "Share" and "Edit".

Comment: Thanks. I did not know. However, this might not be sufficient in a top journal. I believe that it is put somewhere in a book. So the first referees' question might be, why do I put a reference to this site whereas the formal proof exists in a book?