# Upper bound on the trace of the product of real PSD matrices involving the trace of one of them

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, trace, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I am looking at the negative log-likelihood of a multivariate Gaussian $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$:
$$const + (n/2)\log|\Sigma| + (1/2)Tr(\Sigma^{-1}S),$$
where $S = (1/n)\sum(X_i-\mu)(X_i-\mu)'$ is the sample covariance matrix.

And I wonder can we bound the $Tr(\Sigma^{-1}S)$ term with an expression involving only $Tr(\Sigma^{-1})$. I read somewhere<sup>[1]</sup> in SE that if $A, B$ are two real symmetric $n \times n$ PSD matrices, then:
$$Tr(AB) \le \lambda_{max}(B)Tr(A),$$
where $\lambda_{max}(B)$ is the maximal eigenvalue of $B$.

If true, since $\Sigma^{-1}, S$ are real symmetric $p \times p$ PSD matrices, this would mean:
$$Tr(\Sigma^{-1}S) \le \lambda_{max}(S)Tr(\Sigma^{-1})$$

With the help of simulations, I can never find a case where this isn't true. Two main questions:

(1) How do I prove this? (hopefully a process I would understand...)
(2) Is there a better/interesting upper bound involving $Tr(\Sigma^{-1})$ which I'm missing?

<sup>[1] <sub>No idea where it was, otherwise I would probably start from there...</sub></sup>

Comment: Your inequality is true, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321133/upper-bound-for-the-trace-of-the-product-of-a-matrix-and-a-positive-matrix